# I need an UIPickerView or UIDatePicker whit a specific dateFormat

Tags: ios, iphone, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I need a `UIDatePicker` or `UIPickerView` with the following date format:

**yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm**

Do I have to create it ? or is there some `pickerStyle` or `pickerMode` that implements it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply by using a `UIDatePicker` and then set the `pickerMode` for it. Since, you need both Date as well as Time, all you have to do is set the mode to `UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime`

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker;
timePick.datePickerMode =UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
```

The following is provided in the Apple documentation for the above mode-

> The date picker displays dates (as unified day of the week, month, and
>   day of the month values) plus hours, minutes, and (optionally) an
>   AM/PM designation. The exact order and format of these items depends
>   on the locale set. An example of this mode is [ Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM ].

**EDIT:**

In your case, I think the only option you have is to implement two `UIDatePickers`, one with mode set as `UIDatePickerModeDate` and another with `UIDatePickerModeTime`. Then, you can concat them both into an `NSDate`.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: i know it... but with this Mode a can't select the year. only month day hours and minutes... i need years too....                              anyway thank you very much for your answer!!!

Comment: Then I think the only option you have is to implement two UIDatePickers, one with mode set as UIDatePickerModeDate and another with UIDatePickerModeTime. Then, you can concat them both into an NSDate.

Comment: Yes. Thanks and plz accept/upvote if this answers your question.